# Decompress nifti medical image in gz format using python

Tags: python-3.x, gzip, simpleitk, nifti

I want to decompress a butch of nii.gz files in python so that they could be processed in sitk later on. When I decompress a single file manually by right-clicking the file and choosing 'Extract..', this file is then correctly interpreted by sitk (I do sitk.ReadImage(unzipped)). But when I try to decompress it in python using following code:

```
with gzip.open(segmentation_zipped, "rb") as f:
    bindata = f.read()
segmentation_unzipped = os.path.join(segmentation_zipped.replace(".gz", ""))
with gzip.open(segmentation_unzipped, "wb") as f:
    f.write(bindata)
```

I get error when sitk tries to read the file:
*RuntimeError: Exception thrown in SimpleITK ReadImage: C:\d\VS14-Win64-pkg\SimpleITK\Code\IO\src\sitkImageReaderBase.cxx:82:
sitk::ERROR: Unable to determine ImageIO reader for "E:\BraTS19_2013_10_1_seg.nii"*

Also when trying to do it a little differently:

```
input = gzip.GzipFile(segmentation_zipped, 'rb')
s = input.read()
input.close()

segmentation_unzipped = os.path.join(segmentation_zipped.replace(".gz", ""))
output = open(segmentation_unzipped, 'wb')
output.write(s)
output.close()
```

I get:
*RuntimeError: Exception thrown in SimpleITK ReadImage: C:\d\VS14-Win64-pkg\SimpleITK-build\ITK\Modules\IO\PNG\src\itkPNGImageIO.cxx:101:
itk::ERROR: PNGImageIO(0000022E3AF2C0C0): PNGImageIO failed to read header for file: 
Reason: fread read only 0 instead of 8*

can anyone help?

Comment: It's weird that you're getting errors from SimpleITK, since you're not reading the image with SimpleITK (at least in the code you show).  Note that SimpleITK.ReadImage can read a '.nii.gz' file without decompressing it.

Answer (score 4):

No need to unzip the Nifti images, libraries such as `Nibabel` can handle it without decompression.

```
#==================================
import nibabel as nib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#==================================
# load image (4D) [X,Y,Z_slice,time]
nii_img  = nib.load('path_to_file.nii.gz')
nii_data = nii_img.get_fdata()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(number_of_frames, number_of_slices,constrained_layout=True)
fig.canvas.set_window_title('4D Nifti Image')
fig.suptitle('4D_Nifti 10 slices 30 time Frames', fontsize=16)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
mng.full_screen_toggle()

for slice in range(number_of_slices):
    # if your data in 4D, otherwise remove this loop
    for frame in range(number_of_frames):
        ax[frame, slice].imshow(nii_data[:,:,slice,frame],cmap='gray', interpolation=None)
        ax[frame, slice].set_title("layer {} / frame {}".format(slice, frame))
        ax[frame, slice].axis('off')

plt.show()
```

Or you can Use SimpleITK as following:

```
import SimpleITK as sitk
import numpy as np

# A path to a T1-weighted brain .nii image:
t1_fn = 'path_to_file.nii'

# Read the .nii image containing the volume with SimpleITK:
sitk_t1 = sitk.ReadImage(t1_fn)

# and access the numpy array:
t1 = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(sitk_t1)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! that's exactly what I want to do: i really want to use simple itk to read image, but i have loads of nii.gz files. That's why I would like to be able to unpack them in python to be able to use simple itk. I tried to read image in nii.gz format using simple itk but the effect was: RuntimeError: Exception thrown in SimpleITK ReadImage: C:\d\VS14-Win64-pkg\SimpleITK\Code\IO\src\sitkImageReaderBase.cxx:82:
sitk::ERROR: Unable to determine ImageIO reader for "\BraTS19_2013_10_1_seg.nii.gz"

Comment: @ Biba, but SimpleITK can read the compressed format! `sitk_3D = sitk.ReadImage(
            os.path.join(DIR_DATA, "3D_Brain_Source.nii.gz"))`

Comment: When I try to read zipped nifti using itk i get: RuntimeError: Exception thrown in SimpleITK ReadImage: C:\d\VS14-Win64-pkg\SimpleITK\Code\IO\src\sitkImageReaderBase.cxx:82:
sitk::ERROR: Unable to determine ImageIO reader for "BraTS19_2013_10_1_seg.nii.gz". When I unzip the file manually (right click -> extract file) and then  read the file by itk the file is correctly read

Comment: sorry! your solution actually worked, it turned out that there was some problem with the path: i changed to simply D:\BraTS19_2013_10_1_seg.nii.gz and everything worked well! thanks for helping!